# ClearDB connecting with 'npm run start' but not with Heroku deploy; ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, npm, cleardb

I deployed a node app on Heroku and set up ClearDB with MySQL Workbench. When I use `npm run start` it works great, data shows up. When I open in Heroku; `heroku local web` and `heroku open` the app is deployed but no data is displayed. The error message is **resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**.

My database is tiny, so the size limit is not an issue. My `Procfile` is set to

```
web: npm run start
```

**Why isn't my clearDB connecting through Heroku?**

Some other answers I've read involve an `.env` file, which I didn't have. I tried creating one with the `DATABASE_URL` but no change. I also tried adding `port: process.env.PORT || 3036` to my database config file.

I can connect to the Heroku / ClearDB database through MySQL Workbench and all the tables are there.

My database config file:

```
import mysql from 'mysql'

let pool = mysql.createPool({
connectionLimit: 10,
user: '******',
password: '*******',
host: '*******',
database: '*******',
port: process.env.PORT || 3036
});

let chirprdb = {};

chirprdb.all = () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM chirps', (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        return resolve(results);
    })
})
}

export default chirprdb;
```

Expected result: see the app and all its data on the deployed Heroku URL

Actual result: seeing the app but no data is loading, error is resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

**Edit**
I changed the database (so as to not publish my credentials here) and created a new connection with MySQL Workbench. Clicking 'test connection' gave me this warning [image].

router that imports chirperdb

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import db from '../db'

let router = Router();

router.get('/:id?', async (req, res) => {
let id = req.params.id;
if (id) {
    try {
        let results = await db.one(id);
        res.json(results);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
} else {
    try {
        let results = await db.all();
        res.json(results);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I would remove your credentials from the question. With that being said, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED usually points to an issue with connecting to your desired resource, in this case your database. This could be due to a wrong IP address, an incorrect port, the server is listening on the wrong port, or a credentials issue. Can you compare your connection string from your workbench to the one your code resolves? Also, where are you using chirprdb? Maybe post that section of code too

Comment: Port is usually 3306 not 3036

Comment: changed port #, posted chirperdb code, double checked url

Comment: @NathanWright what are the correct ports? I had the app listening on process.env.PORT || 3000.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, before you do anything else, change your ClearDB credentials. You've posted them here and you can't trust them anymore. Editing the question to remove them isn't enough.**

> Some other answers I've read involve an `.env` file, which I didn't have. I tried creating one with the `DATABASE_URL` but no change.

Don't use an `.env` file on Heroku. That file is just a roundabout way of populating environment variables, but Heroku [supports environment variables natively](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). If you need to set environment variables, do it with `heroku config:set` or the web interface.

> I also tried adding `port: process.env.PORT || 3036` to my database config file.

The `PORT` environment variable is the port your web server needs to listen on, not the port you should use to connect to your database. There should be a `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` environment variable already set by the ClearDB addon. Use that (or individual `CLEARDB_` variables, if you must) to connect to MySQL.

You can use the [`parse-database-url` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-database-url) to parse the single `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` value and connect to your database.